# Solipsism, except everyone shares a single mind?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, solipsism

It's conceivable that I could suddenly switch places with someone else. I'm not talking about our brains switching places, but rather, from now on, my mind experiencing the other person's qualia. Since I would have the other person's memories, I wouldn't even realize something happened.

Then, it would be conceivable that these switches happen billions of times per second. Every time some conscious being feels something, my mind switches places to experience their qualia.

So basically, there would actually just be one single mind shared among everyone.

An argument for this would be the fact that a person can survive the loss of either hemisphere of the brain, so if my brain was divided in two and placed into two different bodies, which one would would be me? According to this theory, both would be me - I've been experiencing the qualia from both sides of my brain, and I'll keep experiencing them even after they've been separated.

Is there a name for this theory? Are there any arguments for/against it?

Comment: "My mind experiencing the other person's qualia" is a contradiction in terms. Given the concept of qualia, if it is *your* mind experiencing them then they are no longer *other person's*, you can not stay you, *and* become the other person at the same time. Qualia are not transferable in this way by definition, and something so transferable is not qualia. If everything is transferable then qualia do not exist. A single shared mind is popular in Oriental philosophies as [Atman=Brahman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advaita_Vedanta), but one has to give up personhood to experience it

Comment: @Conifold I agree. By "experiencing the other person's qualia", I mean from now on experiencing the qualia generated by their body rather than my old body (I switch places with the other person).

Comment: That does not work either. If the qualia are generated by bodies then "you" are inseparable from your body, and "you" experiencing other body's qualia is nonsensical. And if they are not generated by bodies, and "you" retain your immaterial identity in the process, then what you will be experiencing isn't anybody else's qualia, it's yours from a new input. Qualia is a wrong concept to use in this context, and trying to think about shared consciousness by analogy to shared material signals only leads to nonsense.